# The assignment of eigen::solve's return value costs lots of time

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

In my work, I need to calculate the inverse matrix (Mat Original in my code), and B here is the identity matrix. The matrix is too huge (56000*56000) to use $solver.solve(B)$ directly, instead, I need to calculate each column of inverse matrix one by one. If I don't use the assignment operation like the code below, the process is fast, which costs 30 seconds.

```
Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> solver;
solver.compute(Original);
for(int i = 0; i< B.cols();i++){
  solver.solve(B.col(i));
}
```

But if I need to get the return value of solve(), the work becomes very time-consuming.

```
Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> solver;
solver.compute(Original);
Vec x(Original.rows());
for(int i = 0; i< B.cols();i++){
  x = solver.solve(B.col(i));
}
```

So anyone knows the reason for time-consuming? Or Is there any other methods to calculate the inverse matrix?

Comment: The return type of `solve(...)` isn't a `Vec`, it's only an expression evaluated to one upon assignment.

Comment: So it means that the solve() function works only upon assignment?

Comment: Pretty much. Yup.